# Updating inline template to Ember 1.0 pre 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I've got some of the following code: https://gist.github.com/c111cf9a240a078c9f6a (in rails)

I'm using ember-latest:

`// Version: v1.0.0-pre.2-2-g1e4bdd5`

`// Last commit: 1e4bdd5 (2012-10-25 14:04:52 -0700)`

The blog post on 1.0 pre 2 http://emberjs.com/blog/2012/10/25/ember-1-0-pre2/ says that inline templates must always be named.

If I add `data-template-name="application"` to each of the three templates, none of them are being executed (supposedly overwritten).

How do I still support this use case without adding a router or something drastic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer appears to be to make a single template that wraps the whole index.html.erb and give it the `data-template-name="application"`.

https://gist.github.com/4008652

This makes sense, as there's no reason to have three templates in the one index.html.erb.

However, I could still see there being a use case for having multiple "application" templates.